# Reading a text file of values 0-1 in R: data gets corrupted when converted to numeric

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read the simplest of csv files but there seems to be a problem when trying to convert the data to numerical. This is the minimal code and output:

```
initialsoltext=read.csv('initialsol.txt', header = FALSE, sep = "")
initialsoltext

output:  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1 [1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0]
as.numeric(initialsoltext)
output:  [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

The csv file is not the issue since the text is read properly - what can possibly happen during the conversion of the last 0?
I tried replacing the "[" and "]" thinking that maybe the last bracket was read as a 1 but it doesn't make a difference.
Thanks to anyone who can help,

Comment: Is this exactly what you are seeing in R? This doesn't look right. If you indent your code input/output with 4 spaces it should look more like it does in R.

Comment: `as.numeric` should never add an additional element to a vector it's called on. Can you provide the file you're reading in so we can try to reproduce?

Comment: It will be easier for us to help you if you provide us with [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That way we can run the code and explore your issue.

Comment: I am new to this and cannot find how to attach a file in an easy way. It is a text file with just the following :  [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]

Comment: It is reading the first and last values as factors (as they are attached to the square brackets), and the `as.numeric` is then reproducing the factor number, which is 1, as there is only one value.  Try `str(initialsoltext)` to check the variable types.

Comment: Are you reading in a csv? If so you should change `sep = ","`. That might be having an impact on your file import

Comment: @AndrewGustar : correct, it is reading the first and last one as factors. The brackets are the problem. Assuming there is no way to write that file without the brackets, how can I read the file without the brackets? I am exploring the read.csv options as well as gsub function but so far no luck.

Comment: It is probably easier to read it in as you are and then remove the brackets with something like `initialsoltext2 <- as.numeric(gsub("[\\[\\]]","",as.character(initialsoltext)))` - this produces a vector of integers that you can then convert to a data.frame if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to apply a function to all columns of a `data.frame`. To read the file using `read.csv` and then apply the `gsub` function [Andrew Gustar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7727429/andrew-gustar) wrote to all columns, try:

```
initialsoltext <- read.csv('initialsol.txt', header = FALSE, sep = "",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
initialsoltext[] <- lapply(initialsoltext, function(x) {
  as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "[\\[\\]]", replacement = "", x, perl = TRUE))})

> initialsoltext
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is reading the first and last values as factors (as they are attached to the square brackets), and the `as.numeric` is then reproducing the factor number, which is 1, as there is only one value. Try `str(initialsoltext)` to check the variable types. To avoid this, add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the `read.csv` arguments.

It is probably easier to read it in as you are and then remove the brackets with something like `initialsoltext2 <- as.numeric(gsub("[]\\[]","",as.character(initialsoltext)))` - this produces a vector of integers that you can then convert to a data.frame if you wish

Comment: I cannot get gsub("[\\[\\]]", "", "0]") to return "0", but gsub("[\\[\\]]", "", "0]", perl = TRUE) or gsub("(\\|\\])", "", "0]") works.

Comment: @KristofferWintherBalling I'm trying this as well - but where do you put the argument with the file name in each of your 2 propositions?

Comment: Strange - it worked on the dataframe.  `gsub("\\[|\\]","","0]")` is equivalent.

Comment: It seems that only`[`needs to be escaped, not `]`, so the regular expression to use is `"[]\\[]"`. Amended above.

Comment: @KristofferWintherBalling for some reason both your options produce an error for me ("unrecognized escape in character string")

Comment: @AndrewGustar changing the accepted answer, as your solution worked on a text string but not on the actual text file.